# bind value to checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" 
 onclick="Utility('<%# Eval("id") %>');"
checked='<%# Eval("Contacted") %> ' />
```

onclick is used to run AJAX, which updates the record in the DB depending on wether the checkbox was selected or unselected.

My Q being....I want to grab 'T' or 'F' which is stored in 'contacted' in code behind
I was trying to do this through the normal binding Eval("Contacted")...(as in code behind 'Contacted' will have the value.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Checked is a boolean property = 'checked' or = '', It is not intended to hold a value, that's what the VALUE attribute is for.

Comment: When i mean value I meant 'true' or 'false' for if it is checked out not, as 'contacted' in code behind will either be t or f...so I wanted it to know what it was stored as

Comment: on an html input checked = "checked" or "", checked="true" doesn't mean anything.  Use an asp.net checkbox control for the behavior you want

Comment: IT IS NOT A TRUE/FALSE FLAG. It is a boolean property that can = 'checked' or ='' < -- nothing.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: @JackPettinger cheers J

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the value of checked (true or false) with:

```
var isChecked = $("#chkbox").is(":checked"); //returns true or false
```

You can set the value with prop

```
$("#chkbox").prop("checked", true); //Sets box to checked.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to achive is something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox" />
```

```
    $('#chkbox').change(function(e) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // do whatever
        }
        else{
            // do whatever
        }
    });
```